# strange encoding issue with strptime

Tags: python, encoding, strptime

I need to convert

> 14 Şubat 2015 Cumartesi, 09:47:49

to datetime. when I print this date it works fine but I couldn't change the encoding inside of  `time.strptime` no matter what I try encoding or decoding to different type. here is my code

```
# -*- coding: cp1254 -*-
import chardet
import time
from time import mktime
import datetime

h="14 Şubat 2015 Cumartesi, 09:47:49"

kc= datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(time.strptime(h.decode('utf-8), "%d %B %Y %A,%H:%M:%S") ))
print kc
```

print chardet.detect(h) result is

```
{'confidence': 0.748485181144929, 'encoding': 'ISO-8859-2'}
```

Comment: Read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html first.

Comment: I'm afraid your questions about SO itself are off-topic here. Read [the help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) and/or post a separate question on https://meta.stackoverflow.com, but briefly, we vote to help future visitors find useful content; and each user has a quota of votes per day, but if you go [serial](http://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed), the system will restrict you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding this solution was a pain.  This is a Windows solution.  It wasn't clear from your post what OS you were using.  Learnings:

- Windows uses different spellings of the locale than *nixs.  It must be `trk` or `turkish`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf(v=vs.90).aspx
- The string passed to datetime must be encoded in the preferred locale encoding.  In this case `cp1254`.  `getlocale()` indicates the correct encoding. https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html (Note 1 at bottom).
- Python doesn't pass the [Turkey Test](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html).  Python 2.7.9 (at least) has a bug in `strptime` in that it won't accept *Şubat*, but will accept *şubat*.  The solution was to `.lower()` the string before processing.  Python 2 and 3 had problems with the uppercase versions of months as well.

#### Python 2.7.9 Solution

Here's the solution with the `.lower()` workaround.  I specifically used a source encoding of `utf-8` to make explicit that the strings used by `strptime` must be in the correct `cp1254` encoding.

```
# coding: utf8
import locale
import datetime
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'turkish')
print(locale.getlocale())

h = u"14 Şubat 2015 Cumartesi, 09:47:49"
kc = datetime.datetime.strptime(h.lower().encode('cp1254'), '%d %B %Y %A, %H:%M:%S')
print kc
```

Output:

```
('Turkish_Turkey', '1254')
2015-02-14 09:47:49
```

#### Python 3.4.2 Solution

Python 3's default of using Unicode for everything makes things simpler, plus the case problem with *Şubat* is fixed.

```
# coding: utf8
import locale
import datetime
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'turkish')
print(locale.getlocale())

h = '14 Şubat 2015 Cumartesi, 09:47:49'
kc = datetime.datetime.strptime(h, '%d %B %Y %A, %H:%M:%S')
print(kc)
```

Output:

```
('Turkish_Turkey', '1254')
2015-02-14 09:47:49
```

Answer (score 1):

h should be a unicode string:

```
h=u"14 Şubat 2015 Cumartesi, 09:47:49"
```

I believe you need to change the line to:

```
kc= datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(time.strptime(h.encode('utf-8'), "%d %B %Y %A,%H:%M:%S") ))
```

(Can't verify becuase I don't know the locale, and I'm getting error becuase of it)

Make sure your locale is set to identify `Şubat` and `Cumartesi`

With:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, <your locale>)
```

Comment: I have tried encoding and decoding these types; cp1254,ascii,utf-8,ISO-8859-2,ISO-8859-9. it didnt help :(

Comment: OP, you didn't pay attention to the answer given. The string literal needs to be declared properly.

Comment: @msw it doesnt matter. Is it possible to  you to post output of this answer?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to create a `datetime` object out of a string representation of a Turkish date.

First thing you need to do is to change your file's source code encoding from `cp1254` to `utf-8` which basically covers broader set of characters.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Secondly, you should set your locale to `tr_TR` in order for Python to understand what `Şubat` means when creating date object.

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "tr_TR")
```

Then, you can do the following for converting your date string to an actual `datetime.datetime` object.

```
import datetime

str_date = '14 Şubat 2015 Cumartesi, 09:47:49'
date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(str_date, "%d %B %Y %A, %H:%M:%S")

print date_obj
# will print datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 14, 9, 47, 49)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: sadly it raises  " locale.Error('locale emulation only supports "C" locale')" at  gae console.. if I change it to" locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')" it gives "ValueError: time data '14 \xc5\x9eubat 2015 Cumartesi, 09:47:49' does not match format '%d %B %Y %A, %H:%M:%S'"

Comment: The encoding **is** tr_TR. Try `u"14  Şubat 2015 Cumartesi"`, OP.

Comment: I guess there is no solution . it is like strptime's bug or smth. I just made a dict of months which maps to numbers.

Comment: If your installation lacks locale support for Turkish, the standard method is not going to work. Maybe investigate why your locales are incomplete.

Comment: @tripleee I dont think it is relevant to localization but the encoding is. if the local support were problem I would see smth like "14 Şubat 2015 Cumartesi, 09:47:49" doesn not match format.

Comment: The string gets converted to Unicode internally and because you're in a different locale, [its UTF-8 encoding](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/015E/index.htm) gets shown with backslashed character codes.